# Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

So this is my HTML code where I'm trying to get whatever is outputted in the div **`abc`** to a downloadable pdf file.

```
<!-- Page Heading -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">
            Reports
        </h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li>
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>  <a href="dashboard">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Reports
            </li>

        </ol>
        <body>
          <div id="abc">
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="cmd">Download Survey Report</button>
        <div id="abc">

        </div>
        </body>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
        <script>

                var doc = new jsPDF();
                var specialElementHandlers = {
                  '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        $('#cmd').click(function () {
            doc.fromHTML($('#abc').html(), 15, 15, {
                'width': 170,
                    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            });
            doc.save('SurveyReport.pdf');
        });
        </script>


        <script>
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
          if(user){
            var userID = user.uid;
            RetrieveSurvey(userID,1,PrintSurvey(document.getElementById("abc")));
          }
        })
        </script>

    </div>
</div>
```

And I'm getting this error on the console:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined"

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I even added `jsPDF` in the script tag...

Comment: put your script inside `<body>` tag and try again.

Comment: Why do you have `<body></body>` tags *inside* a `<div>`?  Also `id`s are supposed to be **unique**, you *cannot* have 2 `id="abc"` tags.

Answer (score 84):

Use this:

```js
window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for!

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Comment: Working fine. Thanks

Comment: Working fine. However, just to be clear for anyone using this for the first time...I used this code at the top of my script file. Not sure if it works within script tags inside the html file.

Comment: Can someone explain what this line does. I presume that window.jsPDF becomes a new property of the window obj, but what  is window.jspdf.jsPDF? Does window.jspdf represent the jsPDF scriptfile, and is the .jsPDF an obj within that file?

Answer (score 11):

First of all your HTML is invalid. Check [W3S](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp).

Put your link to `jspdf` inside `<head>` tag, you can do it even inside `<body>` tag.

Replace your `jspdf` script with latest one:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 9):

as mentioned in https://github.com/matb/jsPDF use

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

add this script in head tag

Answer (score 4):

@https://stackoverflow.com/users/4833506/nikkorian

window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;

This approach assigns the jsPDF object, which is a property of the jspdf object on the window, to the jsPDF property on the window. The effect is that you can use jsPDF directly instead of having to use jspdf.jsPDF.

However, it's important to note that while this approach can work in certain situations, it may not be ideal for larger, more complex applications or when working with modules. Using global variables can potentially lead to naming conflicts or issues with variable scope.

In a larger application or in a module-based environment, it would be better to import jsPDF into each module where it's used. However, given the context and the simplicity of your application, the approach you've taken is perfectly fine and can be a quick way to solve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

use this:

```
window.jsPDF = require('jspdf');
```

instead of this:

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for contributing. However, I would edit your answer to add additional explanation. For more help, see [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).